# How do i modify an ArrayList from one Activity in a separate Activity

Tags: java, android

How do i add more `Cars` to my `ArrayList<Car>` from a separate `Activity`?

Because I have something like this :

```
 private List<Car> getData() {

 List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

cars.add(new Car("Dodge", "Viper"));

cars.add(new Car("Chevrolet", "Corvette"));

cars.add(new Car("Aston Martin", "Vanquish"));

cars.add(new Car("Lamborghini", "Diablo"));

cars.add(new Car("Ford", "Pinto"));

return cars;

}
```

But cars are only example, I have textswitcher in one application and I want to get text from textswitcher and place it as new item in other Activity with listview.

Comment: What exactly do you want to edit?

Comment: I want to add new data as in example :cars.add(...)

Comment: yes you can do using io streams..

Comment: Fixed his question, should be easier now.

Comment: @user1560197 why you want to do this ???

Comment: I want to update my list view. And I have no other ideas ;p

Comment: @user1560197 i think you should use **database** like `sqllite` for permanent storage, this is not the way to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: it looks like you could use some kind of **DAO** outside of both Activities

Answer (score 0):

Just make your List a class variable and have an addCar function

```
public void addCar(String make,String model){
      cars.add(new Car(make,model));
}
```

and change getData()

```
    private List<Car> getData() {

            addCar("Dodge", "Viper");
            addCar("Chevrolet", "Corvette");
            etc...

        return cars;

    }
```

and in your other Activity just call addCar(make,model)

Comment: In the second `Activity` he would need a reference to the first one to do it, wouldn't he?

Comment: yes, shouldn't be a problem though. Although I don't know what his class/code looks like. He doesn't state any constraints

Comment: But cars are only example, I have textswitcher in one application and I want to get text from textswitcher and place it as new item in other Activity with listview.

Comment: You really should look into `sqlite` and creating a table for your data. Take a look at my answer for more detail. Attempting to do what you are saying is not good practice and would be a major headache to change and implement. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782674/427763

Answer (score 0):

Put `cars` into intent, which starts second `Activity` with `putExtra()`. Then retrieve it with `getExtra()` and add the cars you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the other `Activity` will exist in memory once you leave it (as the system may destroy it if memory resources become low). You should save your data to persistent storage (i.e. a database or `SharedPreferences`) or pass the data as an `Intent` extra instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are going to need to pass the object to the other `Activity` for modification using `Intents`. **HOWEVER**, this seems very **wrong**. I would suggest re-thinking how you are adding `Cars` to your `ArrayList` outside of the `Activity`.

As Harmeet Singh mentioned, you might want to look into creating a `sqlite` table that will hold all your `Cars`. Then you can have your `ListView` have a `CursorAdapter` that is looking at that table. This will allow you add `Cars` from anywhere and will be MUCH more flexible and better practice.

Here are two posts that discuss passing the objects as `Intents` to your other `Activity` BUT again, i do not suggest you continue down this road to implement what you are asking. Go with `sqlite` and a database table.

1. [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)
2. [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should use **database** like `sqllite` or to share a **common resource** like a `xml` file or any for **permanent storage**, this is not the way to make storage, as this type of storage is **volatile**.

All your data will go **clean** if memory clears in any case.

have a look [android persistent storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)